# Validar tipo de dato

Tags: validación, haskell, type

Necesito validar el tipo de dato en una función haskell, pero no entiendo como hacerlo. Lo que quiero hacer es convertir un tipo de dato a un String:

```
type T = [TB]
data TB= SmallWord String | Blank | BigWord String
             deriving (Eq,Show)
```

Blank es un espacio en blanco, y BigWord es string que se debe unir con el siguiente (usualmente SmallWord). Entre cada elemento hay un espacio con excepción de BigWord. Actualmente tengo:

```
converti :: T -> String
converti (x:xs) = converti2 x ++ " " ++ converti xs

converti2 :: TB -> String
converti2 (SmallWord p) = p
converti2 (Blank) = " "
converti2 (BigWord w) = w
```

Sin embargo, la validación de BigWord y que se una con el siguiente Word o BigWord no entiendo como hacerla. Aquí un ejemplo del resultado:

```
[SmallWord "la", BigWord "cami", SmallWord "sa", Blank, SmallWord "azul"]

result: "la camisa  azul"  -- entre camisa y azul hay dos espacios por Blank
```

Comment: ¿Y qué pasa si el siguiente de un `BigWord` es un `Blank`?

Comment: En este caso se omite el Blank y se busca el siguiente BigWord o SmallWord

Answer (score 1):

Casi ya lo tienes. Una forma podría dejar a `converti2` que decida el espacio de separación:

```hs
converti :: T -> String
converti (x:xs) = converti2 x ++ converti xs

converti2 :: TB -> String
converti2 (SmallWord p) = p
converti2 (Blank) = " " ++ " "
converti2 (BigWord w) = w ++ " "
```

Pero puedes acabar con un espacio de más al final de muchas frases.

Un modo de controlar mejor es juntar ambas funciones y considerar todos los casos:

```hs
converti :: T -> String
converti "" = ""
-- elemento final
converti (Blank : "") = ""
converti (Bigword x : "") = x
converti (Smallword x : "") = x
-- separación con espacio
converti (Blank : xs) = " " ++ converti xs
converti (Bigword x : xs) = x ++ " " ++ converti xs
-- si es Smallwords miramos el siguiente elemento
converti (Smallword x : Blank : xs) = converti (Smallword x : xs)
converti (Smallword x : Bigword y : xs) = x ++ y ++ converti xs
converti (Smallword x : Smallword y : xs) = converti (Smallword (x ++ y) : xs)
```